# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I tried all the suggestions from the internet.

**I am here trying to save an array of Dictionaries in user Defaults.**

```
let tokenInfo: [String: Any] = ["data": response?.data as Any, "startDate": response?.startDate as Any, "endDate": response?.endDate as Any]
{
 if error == nil
    userDefModel().token = tokenInfo
}
```

In userDefModel Class

```
var token: [String: Any]? {
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "token")
    }
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token") as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the data you are trying to store.

Comment: Sample Data
data: "agfguyorhgvqiguahia9guhhdivisaguh89o3rujgbvu903ugepvy3ploeuvap0-3gv"
startDate = "2019-10-04 18:20:51 +0000";
endDate = "2019-10-05 18:20:51 +0000";

Comment: Good luck to you. I wouldn't put stuff used to hit an endpoint in UserDefaults.

Answer (score -1):

This error due to your dictionary items, try to print the dictionary before setting it to the token.

I think the issue may be in the data, you need to convert it before store it in the dictionary.

```
NSString(data: response!.data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

The other solution:

```
// Save
UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(value), forKey: key)

// Retrieve 
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) as? Data {
        userData = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Profile.self, from: data)
}
```